# A beginner's question on programs that can search and calculate in very large sets

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, programming-languages, search-algorithms

I am not in the computer science field and was looking for some guidance on books/papers/programs that allow me to learn how to design algorithms for problems that involve very large number of calculations and search in very large datasets. Texts that have advanced mathematics is not an issue. I am just looking for some specific resources that help me understand how people in computer science perform seemingly vast operations such as in complicated video games, Google like search etc. I have access to a computer cluster and am fairly familiar with C++, Matlab and Python.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many textbooks on algorithm design.  I suggest checking out standard ones (e.g., ones used in university classes).